# De-opped by accident on my world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

Me and my friend are playing a minecraft survival, but went into creative to do a build. When we finished, I de-opped both of us but I didn't realise he was still in creative.

How do I go about changing him into survival? Or is it not possible?

Comment: Dedicated server or LAN game?

Answer (score 0):

If this a server, (which it seems like it is since minecraft-server tag) then go in the console and do this command: `/op <Your IGN>` or `/gamemode survival <His IGN>`

Otherwise, if it is an LAN server, you can do something a bit like this:

First, go into the menu (press esc)

Next, select Open to LAN and then go to Allow Cheats as seen here:[image: Allow Cheats]

Then press that button, Start LAN World and voila, you have yourself OP.

You could ALSO just set the gamemode to survival, and then that would put him in survival.